# No funciona la insertacion de datos desde my php a mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

He tratado que el código se ejecute pero no funciona.

Ya verifiqué el nombre de la columnas y cómo las llamo, también la conexión, de igual manera el formulario.

Lo que creo que falla es el `INSERT INTO` pero no sé en qué, o qué estará fallando para que el código no se ejecute adecuadamente, por que cada vez que lo pruebo, los datos no son insertados, pero los datos sí son enviados y almacenados en las variables.

No sé si es un problema con el `INSERT INTO` o si es la tabla que no me permite la conexión o no acepta la introducción de datos.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = 'root';

$dbpass = 'root';

$dbtabla ='dbcuentas';

$dbport = 3306;

 $conx = mysqli_connect("$dbhost:$dbport" , $dbuser , $dbpass);

   $dbdato = mysqli_select_db( $conx, $dbtabla );


$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];

$movil = $_POST['telefono'];



$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta( usuario, password, email, cedula, movil)
 VALUES('$usuario', '$password', '$email', $cedula, $movil)";



$peticion = mysqli_query( $insert, $dbdato );

if($peticion){
  echo 'lo lograste porfin';
}

else{
  echo 'vamos sigue intentando';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con que usuario estas ingresando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con sentencias preparadas para evitar inyección SQL. Esta es la estructura sugerida en la [página oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

```
<?php
/* El puerto es innecesario ya que MySql usa el 3306 por defecto*/
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "dbcuentas");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Preparar una sentencia INSERT */
$consulta = "INSERT INTO cuenta (usuario, password, email, cedula, movil) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

$sentencia->bind_param("sssii", $usuario, $password, $email, $cedula, $movil);

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$movil = $_POST['telefono'];

/* Ejecutar la sentencia */
$sentencia->execute();

/* cerrar la sentencia */
$sentencia->close();

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Gracias, la verda aun los datos no se podian inbsertar cuando me fije mas en la tabla verifique los datos en me dicuenta que  el numero telefono lo tenia INT cuando  deberia ser varchar lo cambia y ltu codigo se ejecuto a la perfeccion muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

### Concatenar tus variables

Cuando realizas el query estás enviando tus variables como string y no como variable para eso puedes hacer lo siguiente :

```
$insert = " INSERT INTO cuenta(id, usuario, password, email, cedula, movil) VALUES('', '".$usuario."', '".$password."', '".$email."', '".$cedula."', '".$movil."')";
```

También puedes probar sin las ' ' es decir

```
VALUES(".$usario.",".$password."  ...
```

Tienes el mismo problema en la conexión

```
$conx = mysqli_connect("$dbhost:$dbport" , $dbuser , $dbpass);
```

Llama a las variables

```
$conx = mysqli_connect($dbhost.":".$dbport, $dbuser , $dbpass);
```

Comment: aun los datos no se insertan en la tabla

Comment: Verifica en tu html si los input corresponden a esas variables